# Trello will not open my card

Tags: trello

I go to open one of my cards to update my checklists, I click the card, the window darkens as usual, but the card never appears. I've tried going to the specific card's link as well as copying the check list(s) to a new card and it will not open.

The strange thing is that other cards will open, and there is no consistency between the cards that do open and the cards that won't as to whether or not I'm assigned to the card, or where the card is located (ie. different lists). It doesn't even matter if there are more or less checklist items in the particular card, so I know it cannot be a loading problem because of the size.

Please help. I would really appreciate being able to keep myself organized.

Comment: We figured out the problem. I was numbering things like so "#1, #2, etc." and that caused a problem because of the links it created to the card with the corresponding number.

Once I updated my lists and simply removed the # then I was able to open the cards. However, I was only able to access the card to update them on my husband's phone, since the trello app doesn't create a link with # and a number.

Comment: please post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

We figured out the problem. I was numbering things like so "#1, #2, etc." and that caused a problem because of the links it created to the card with the corresponding number. Once I updated my lists and simply removed the #, then I was able to open the cards. However, I was only able to access the cards to update them on my husband's phone, since the Trello app doesn't create a link with # and a number.