# Trello will not open my card

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Card not opening](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33489/card-not-opening)

Is something going on with Trello today? I am trying to reply to someone on one of my cards but when I try to click on the card I get a "overlay" 50% black color screen and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like an issue with scripting error.  The first steps I would try would be:

1. a. Log out.
   b. Reload the page.
   c. Log back in.
2. a. Log out.
   b. Restart your browser.
   c. Log back in.
3. a. Log out.
   b. Clear your browser cookies and cache (should be able to do in most from the preferences screens).
   c. Log back in.
4. a. Log out.
   b. Reboot your system.
   c. Log back in.